# Detect when user plays music when app is closed

Tags: ios, swift

I was wondering if there is a way the app could know if a user started to play music from the Music app or any other source (Spotify etc.). I am trying to do a specific function every time a user plays a song even if my app is not active. Is this even possible? Can I also retrieve the song information?

Comment: No,you can’t do this if you want your app on the store

Answer (score 0):

With `AVKit` you can make use:

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().isOtherAudioPlaying
```

> A Boolean value indicating whether another app is currently playing
>   audio.

Note that this will **not** work when your app is inactive. You can´t do that and Apple will reject your app. You can only make this check if your app is active.

Comment: How would this work if the app isn’t  currently active?

Comment: @Paulw11 it won´t of course. I was a bit fast with hitting the post button.

Comment: Ya I get that but how does that work when the app is inactive

Comment: It **doesn't** work when the app is inactive. That's not possible.